# Кодирование Хаффмана

Tags: java, huffman

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, написать сюда для меня было уже последней мерой

```
Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();


String string = in.nextLine();
    int value;
    char key;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        key = string.charAt(i);
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            value = map.get(key) + 1; // получение значения по ключу те частоту
            map.put(key,value);
        } else {
            map.put(key,1);
        }
    }

List list = new ArrayList(map.entrySet());

Comparator<Map.Entry<Character,Integer>> comparator =  new Comparator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> a, Map.Entry<Character, Integer> b) {
        return a.getValue() - b.getValue();
    }
};

Collections.sort(list,comparator);
System.out.println(list);
System.out.println(map);
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

У меня есть неотсортированный map и отсортированный список пар. С помощью метода .get я могу получить член listа. Не могли бы вы подсказать, как мне получить значение переменной value и key этого члена? 
Те, например, моя программа при вводе теста: 
bbbcdee
Выводит весь лист так: 
[c=1, d=1, e=2, b=3]
при .get(0)
c=1
как отдельно получить само значение типа char? (В данном случае 'c', в общем случае это наш ключ/key)
и отдельно получить значения типа int (в данном случае это 5, в общем случае это наш значение/value)

Надеюсь я смог понятно поставить задачу, заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Кучно пошли студентики, интересно откуда они все? Такое ощущение что препод у них один и тот же ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, я бы рекомендовал использовать generic List.

```
List<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.EntrySet());
```

Тогда `list.get(0)` будет возвращать `Map.Entry<Character, Integer>`, у которого есть методы `getKey()` и `getValue()`, которые и вернут соответственно ключ и значение.